# Easy search in Yii gridview?

Tags: php, yii

In `yii` during search when we enter any string yii `Search function` search that `string` in related model like `%string%` . I want to make search easy like I want to search like `%string` or `string%` but that causing `error`.

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);

    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true); // That didn't work

    $criteria->compare('course',$this->course,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                ));
}
```

When I search id `123` it searches all result with  id with `123` but when it returns `%123` I stop searching. I am doing this from front end filter box in `gridview`

Comment: I think you not specify all attributes in rule function as "safe",'on'=>'search'

Answer (score 0):

Try using add  addSearchCondition instead of compare

```
 $criteria->addSearchCondition('name', $this->name);
```

*be sure you column is string type*